# not registered on network and seems the imei is changed

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, mobile-network

I have an international version of galaxy s3 gt i9300 it had android 4.0.4 working fine when i bought it(second hand) then i upgraded it to 4.3. Since then it performs as a normal device would but can not connect to network with error **NOT REGISTERED ON NETWORK**. I've searched a lot and not successful but with a clear cause of all this. It seems the IMEI in the device differ from the one on the back under the battery.

So how do i restore the original imei? I've seen a couple of solutions that don't work.

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset?

Comment: yes I have done lot's of ways, I even have degraded to 4.1 official but no luck